# Search geo_distance with aggregations in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a geospatial searce, since I can get multiple hits with the same `listing_id` I'd like to group the results by the `listing_id`.

```
{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "24km",
                "location":[39.91774, -75.03005]
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_listing": {
            "terms": { "field": "listing_id" }
        }
    }
}
```

If I search without the aggregation the results come back fine, but whenever I try adding an aggregation node I receive the following error
`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"listings","node":"n0nkglP4T6iik-Z-XyYspA","reason":{"type":"parse_exception","reason":"failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"}}]},"status":400}`

This is the curl request:
`curl -XPOST http://192.168.10.10:9200/listings/route/_search -d '{"query":{"filtered":{"filter":{"geo_distance":{"distance":"24km","location":[39.91774, -75.03005]}}},"aggs":{"group_by_listings":{"terms":{"field":"listing_id"}}}}}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to move your `aggs` out of the `query` part, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "24km",
          "location": [
            39.91774,
            -75.03005
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_listing": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "listing_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```